# Cannot run uiautomatorviewer.bat from Android sdk tools

Tags: android, batch-file, classpath, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to run `uiautomatorviewer.bat` from Android sdk tools.

It was working fine on my previous system, now it's not.

To make it run before I used to edit `*.bat` file by changing last line in `*.bat` file

```bat
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0

rem Get the CWD as a full path with short names only (without spaces)
for %%i in ("%cd%") do set prog_dir=%%~fsi

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call ..\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\uiautomatorviewer-25.3.2.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
set frameworkdir=.

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\lib

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\framework

:JarFileOk

set jarpath=%frameworkdir%\%jarfile%

if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
    set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
    goto SwtDone

:QueryArch

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%frameworkdir%\..\bin\archquery') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%\%%a

:SwtDone

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    exit /B

:SetPath
set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=C:\Android\sdk\tools" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Now when I try to run uiautomatorviewer.bat I see this error:

```
C:\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I was looking for different solutions how to use -classpath, but none of them helped

Comment: Seems like it would have been a lot easier to copy and paste the text from the console into your question then taking a screen shot and posting that.

Comment: @Squashman done, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the .bat file problem.

I had the same problem because I was using Java 10.

When I downgrade Java 10 to Java 8 it starts working again.

Remember to set variables as it is explained here http://www.automationtestinghub.com/setup-java-environment-variables/.

My Java version now on which uiautomatorviewer is working is jdk-8u171-windows-x64.exe.

Comment: I am using Java 9.0.4, I will downgrade to 8 and will let you if it helped, Thank you!

Comment: I did the same thing as mentioned and I am using java 1.8.0_301 but when i open the uiautomator.bat it quickly exits before I could see anything in cmd

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to Java8, which is available in *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201*
Add in Environmental Variable Java_Home.

Open new cmd window in *C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\tools\bin*
Enter uiautomatorviewer.bat

It will work.

Comment: I'm getting a NPE: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.wakeup(MonitorThread.java:453)
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.quit(MonitorThread.java:461)
        at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.terminate(AndroidDebugBridge.java:293)
        at com.android.uiautomator.DebugBridge.terminate(DebugBridge.java:75)
        at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:82)"

Answer (score 1):

The jdk8 installation from [Java Download Page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

It comes with the JRE, you need to have the JRE at the `JAVA_HOME` path, no matter which JDK version you use.

Just download jdk8 and you should be able to run `uiautomatorviewer.bat`